# Can't set different Drawables to recyclerview items

Tags: android, drawable

I have recyclerview with Image, text and description.

Now, when I get data from server, I also got HEX color, and with it, in Asynctask, app will make Drawable with the Color as tint.

But when app loads and all is done, all items drawable matches last item.
[image]

How you see, hats are same colors, but not matching Database' hexes:

[image]

Also logs can approve this:

HatStoreFragment$JSONParse2: Hat Hex: #d61b22Hat name: Punainen Hattu
HatStoreFragment$JSONParse2: Hat Hex: #fff202Hat name: Keltainen Hattu

My Adapter:

package com.developerfromjokela.pusahub;

```
public class HatStoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HatStoreAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    private Context mContext;
    private List<HatStoreCard> appsList;
    private HatAdapterListener listener;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, count;
        public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;
        public CardView cardView;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hattitle);
            count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hatdesc);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.hatthumbnail);
            overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.hatoverflow);
            cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.hatcard_view);
        }
    }


    public HatStoreAdapter(Context mContext, List<HatStoreCard> appsList, HatAdapterListener listener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.appsList = appsList;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.hatstorecardview, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int postition) {
        HatStoreCard app = appsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        holder.title.setText(app.getName());
        holder.count.setText(app.getDescription());

        // loading album cover using Glide library
        if (CardAnimationConfig.animating) {
            setFadeAnimation(holder.cardView);
        }


        Glide.with(mContext).load(app.getAppicon()).into(holder.thumbnail);

        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Drawable: "+ app.getAppicon().toString());
        holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.overflow);
            }
        });
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                listener.onHatSelected(holder.getAdapterPosition(), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getTitle(holder.getAdapterPosition()), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getDescription(holder.getAdapterPosition()), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getThumbnailImage(holder.getAdapterPosition()), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getType(holder.getAdapterPosition()), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getPrice(holder.getAdapterPosition()), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getDownloadableRes(holder.getAdapterPosition()), appsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getRequiredVersion(), appsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getHatID());
            }
        });

        holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onHatSelected(holder.getAdapterPosition(), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getTitle(holder.getAdapterPosition()), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getDescription(holder.getAdapterPosition()), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getThumbnailImage(holder.getAdapterPosition()), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getType(holder.getAdapterPosition()), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getPrice(holder.getAdapterPosition()), HatDetailsArrayHelper.getDownloadableRes(holder.getAdapterPosition()), appsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getRequiredVersion(), appsList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getHatID());
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
     */
    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        // inflate menu
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.storecard_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }

    /**
     * Click listener for popup menu items
     */
    class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

        public MyMenuItemClickListener() {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_download:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ladataan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return appsList.size();
    }

    public interface HatAdapterListener {

        void onHatSelected(int position, String hatname, String hatdescription, String hatthumbnail, String hattype, int hatprice, String appdownloadableres, int requiredversion, int hatID);
    }

    public Intent getItemIntent(int postition, Context context) {
       Intent intent =  intents.get(postition);
       return intent;
    }
    private void setFadeAnimation(View view) {
        AlphaAnimation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(200);
        view.startAnimation(anim);
    }




}
```

And the HatStoreCard Class:

```
public class HatStoreCard {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Drawable appicon;
    private int hatID;
    private int requiredVersion;

    public HatStoreCard() {
    }

    public HatStoreCard(String name, String description, Drawable haticon, int requiredVersion, int hatID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.appicon = haticon;
        this.requiredVersion = requiredVersion;
        this.hatID = hatID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getRequiredVersion() {
        return requiredVersion;
    }

    public int getHatID() {
        return hatID;
    }

    public void setHatID(int hatID) {
        this.hatID = hatID;
    }

    public void setRequiredVersion(int version) {
        this.requiredVersion = version;
    }

    public void setAppicon(Drawable appicon) {
        this.appicon = appicon;
    }
    public Drawable getAppicon() {
        return appicon;
    }
}
```

I hope there is enough logs and info about this.

If someone can say why this is happening, huge thanks to him.

Edit:
Here is the code, where Drawable gets made:

```
if (apptype.equals("tint")) {

                        Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_hat_cropped_v3);
                        icon.setTintMode(MULTIPLY);
                        icon.setTint(Color.parseColor(appdownloadableres));
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Hat Hex: "+appdownloadableres+ "Hat name: "+apptitle);


                        final HatStoreCard a = new HatStoreCard(apptitle, appshortdesc, icon, supportversion, hatID);
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {

                            // Stuff that updates the UI
                              appsList.add(a);


                        });
                    }
```

*If this was an duplicate, I am so sorry, I didn't found answers (maybe the my knowledge of English language is bad, so I didn't search right questions to get answer that I need).*

Regards,
Developer From Jokela

Comment: How is `appdownloadableres` assigned?

Comment: 'appdownloadableres' is from JSONObject, which comes from server. So, the appdowbloadableres can't be a problem, because Getting String from JSONObject is not Problem, because the Hat name are different and correct.

Comment: I was only making sure you're not assigning the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you load a `Drawable` object from a resource, you'll get a unique `Drawable` object instance. **However**, each of these unique drawables will **share** a single [`Drawable.ConstantState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.ConstantState) object. When you modify the tint of a drawable, that's part of this constant state, so even though it looks like you're modifying a unique drawable, you'll actually affect every other drawable loaded from the same resource.

When you don't want this optimization, you can call the [`mutate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#mutate()) method on the loaded drawable. So, replace this code:

> ```
> Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_hat_cropped_v3);
> icon.setTintMode(MULTIPLY);
> icon.setTint(Color.parseColor(appdownloadableres));
> ```

with this:

```
Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_hat_cropped_v3);
icon.mutate();
icon.setTintMode(MULTIPLY);
icon.setTint(Color.parseColor(appdownloadableres));
```

Comment: Thank you! Awesome work! Huge thanks to you, this is working!

Answer (score 0):

After changing your item in listener, you should to notify what yours item is changed, so invoke adapter method `notifyDataSetChanged()` which signalize to redraw recycle.

Or if you want more performance use `notifyItemChanged(index)` where index is your element position.

So in your case just and one more parameter in your listener(reference to adapter) and in the end of this method invoke one of the methods what I mention.

Comment: Where I should put it? I have 'adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();' in AsyncTask&#39;s On Post execute, where The code in background has been done.

Comment: Post your listener class, you should to put it in your method `onHatSelected`

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me:

```
Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_hat_cropped_v3);
icon.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(appdownloadableres), MULTIPLY);
image.setBackgroundDrawable(icon);
```